# FET-based H-Bridge for bi-color LED

Tags: led, mosfet, raspberry-pi, h-bridge

I've got a bi-color LED in a push-button that is *red* when powered in one direction and *green* in the other direction. I would like to control it from a Raspberry Pi GPIO pin, e.g. High=Red, Low=Green.

I thought I could use some kind of H-Bridge to reverse the polarity, something like this perhaps?

[image]

The idea is that when input is *High* the BC547 is open and FET **B** and **C** are open providing polarity in one direction. When the input is *Low* the BC547 is closed and the FETs **A** and **B** are open providing polarity in the other direction.

I want to power it from Raspberry Pi's 5V pins however the GPIO is only 3.3V (that I can level shift up to 5V if needed).

The LED doesn't need a resistor, the button has an internal one.

I've put 4x 2N7000 (N-channel MOSFET) in the schematic as I've got a bag of them but happy to replace them with BC547 / BC558 or anything else.

- Is the overall idea correct?
- Will the gate levels be high enough to open the FETs?
- Will the voltage drops on the FETs will still allow the LEDs to operate?

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't you be better just getting a bi-coloured LED with a common cathode and just driving the LEDs individually, rather than needing all that extra circuitry.  You could also just use a single NOT gate if you want to control them off one GPIO.

Comment: @HandyHowie The LED is built in the push button, I can't change it unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

H bridges are for driving high current coils or motors. You have no current limiting R.

CMOS (74HC family ) has about 50 OHms driver R so you can include this with your current limiting R.

Since Iv intensity in xxxx mcd is common now , the curent can reduced to a few mA for indicators with a single Rs = 470 to 1k.
[image: schematic]

Comment: Note that you can do this with 2 x 5V inverters in my answer vs 1x 5V inverters in the accepted answer.  But if you had 5V uC then only 1 inverter needed/

Comment: Also why do you put an extra resistor for the *red* LED? I tried without, with just one shared one like the other answer shows and it worked fine. Using 74HC04. Thanks!

Comment: Since R/G has a different Vf the extra R adds the 1.3V+/-0.2 difference typ 2.1 to 3.4 but reality is choice of LED Iv  from 100mcd to >10,000 mcd at 20mA means you can tune equal brightness by R or choice of LED but the RED will draw more current, then operate at lower current like 5mA..  But Iv efficacy differences can make it look equal

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Thanks for a quick reply!

Comment: So single R is adequate then choose brightest cheap LEDs that are roughly equal and run at low mA  lens reducing angle 50% makes almost 2x brighter

Comment: As for *Note that you can do this with 2 x 5V inverters in my answer vs 3x 5V inverters in the accepted answer.* - good point. Even though 74HC04 comes with 6 anyway so I'm in no shortage here.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I drive bi-color LEDs:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKdFn1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Use a logic family that can source or sink 20ma or whatever you need to drive the LEDs.  I actually don't use inverters (that solution was closest to your circuit), but a serial to parallel shift register (like a 74xx591) to drive 4 bi-color LEDs using the 8 outputs.  For two output pins you end up with 00 -> off, 01 -> red, 10 -> green, 11 = off.

Comment: That's brilliant, thanks! Works like a charm with 74HC04 :)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't upvote with my reputation yet :(